# What’s the best Backtest Software/method?

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio, backtesting

I have a CSV which looks like this.

Ticker | Buy Date | Sell date

AAPL   | 2018-01-03 | 2019-03-30

TSLA   | 2019-03-01| 2019-04-05

What’s the best way to backtest this CSV performance given that every stock is given equal weight?

Looking for a software or python script.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python one of the most complete library for doing backtest is "Backtrader". Have a look at the GitHub page: https://github.com/mementum/backtrader

Comment: isn't there something simpler? I have my orders, need to check performance.